# IOException when using GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push notification to Android devices, but getting an error in following situation.

```
String msg = "push message";
String to1 = "123456";
String from1 = "098776655";
```

This works fine:

```
Message message = new Message.Builder()
    .collapseKey("1")
    .addData("message", msg)
    .addData("to1", to1)
    .addData("to2", to1)
    .build();
```

But getting error when using the following:

```
Message message = new Message.Builder()
    .collapseKey("1")
    .addData("message", msg)
    .addData("to", to1)
    .addData("from", from1)
    .build();
```

I have even used other variables in place of `from1` as well, but still getting error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
```

StackTrace:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
  [run]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  [run]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
  [run]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
  [run]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
  [run]     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1298)
  [run]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  [run]     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1292)
  [run]     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:948)
  [run]     at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
  [run]     at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:363)
  [run]     at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:261)
  [run]     at example.HelloServlet.sendToSingleDevice(HelloServlet.java:173)
  [run]     at example.HelloServlet.doGet(HelloServlet.java:36)
  [run]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
  [run]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
  [run]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  [run]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  [run]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  [run]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  [run]     at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:270)
  [run]     at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
  [run]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  [run]     at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
  [run]     at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:302)
  [run]     at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:163)
  [run]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:283)
  [run]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
  [run]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
  [run]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  [run]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
  [run]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
  [run]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
  [run]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
  [run]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
  [run]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
  [run]     at net.stax.appserver.webapp.RequestMonitorValve.invoke(RequestMonitorValve.java:35)
  [run]     at net.stax.appserver.webapp.RequestSetupValve.invoke(RequestSetupValve.java:31)
  [run]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:647)
  [run]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
  [run]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
  [run]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
  [run]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
  [run]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
  [run] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
  [run]     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1245)
  [run]     at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:373)
  [run]     at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:318)
  [run]     at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:362)
  [run]     ... 33 more
  [run] Exception Message : Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
```

Comment: Why would you even attempt to send two parameters with the same name but different value?

Comment: Sorry, this was just a typing error over here, which i have corrected now...

Comment: According to _GCM_ documentation, the exact failure reason is described in the response.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now i have added stack trace, please suggest me the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Every body i have fixed it...

The problem was nothing i just change

```
.addData("from", from1)
```

To

```
.addData("from1", from1)
```

and it works...

May be `from` is keyword on GCM server side...

Answer (score 0):

This may be you do not have permission to access the url, or you need to install the new certificate, the certificate provided by the server, you need to talk to the server side contact!

Comment: As i have mentioned above that it is working in first scenario but not working in second...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the response you get from the server (the response body), it will tell you that `from` is, indeed, a reserved word (because it is used in `Intent`s in Android, as far as I remember).